# Pivot rows into a single column and index them using column names in R

Tags: r

I need to flip row values into a single column and create an index based on the column name and row number. I checked a lot of pivot solutions in R but none seem to simply flip things around without creating means, sums, etc. Help would be appreciated.

```
df1 <- read.table(textConnection("a1,a2,a3
23,34,4
34,44,98"), sep=",", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(textConnection("id,val
1_a1,23
2_a2,34
3_a3,4
4_a1,34
5_a2,44
6_a3,98"), sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

I need to go from a data frame looking like this:

```
  a1 a2 a3
1 23 34  4
2 34 44 98
```

To this:

```
    id val
1 1_a1  23
2 2_a2  34
3 3_a3   4
4 4_a1  34
5 5_a2  44
6 6_a3  98
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want your "id" column like this? Do you always assume unlisting by the rows?

Comment: I needed a way to keep track of what column they used to reside but have it unique to the new column in the pivoted data set... if that makes sense

Comment: But the order of unlisting is not particularly important?

Comment: Part of why I'm asking is that it often makes more sense to me to not have values pasted together like this when R can deal with multiple columns as grouping variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
m1 <- t(df1)
d1 <- data.frame(id=paste(seq_along(m1), 
        rownames(m1)[row(m1)], sep="_"), val=c(m1))

 d1
 #   id val
 #1 1_a1  23
 #2 2_a2  34
 #3 3_a3   4
 #4 4_a1  34
 #5 5_a2  44
 #6 6_a3  98
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate a base-only solution

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with `gather` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df1, id, val)
```

Note that this requires the latest development version of tidyr, after [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/commit/882b48089c873516c485cf75e8108b04519ced4e)- you can install it with `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")`. Otherwise, you can change the line to `gather(df1, id, val, a1:a3)`.

To add the `1_`, `2_`, etc, you can do:

```
df2$id <- paste(df2$id, 1:nrow(df2), sep = "_")
```

If you use the dplyr package as well, you could do this as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% gather(id, val) %>% mutate(id = paste(id, seq_len(n()), sep = "_"))
```

Comment: I guess you missed creating the `id` column

Comment: @akrun What do you mean? Even in my original revision I included the line `df2$id <- paste(df2$id, 1:nrow(df2), sep = "_")`. And `gather(df1, id, val)` does create the `id` column.

Comment: I meant `gather(df1, id, val)#Error in measure.attributes[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @akrun I cannot reproduce that error. What version of `tidyr` do you have? I have `tidyr_0.1.0.9000`

Comment: same version `tidyr_0.1.0.9000`

Comment: @akrun I still find the discrepancy between behavior on my machine and yours quite strange, and possibly an issue with tidyr. For you, the following three lines in a fresh R session throw an error? `df1 <- structure(list(a1 = c(23L, 34L), a2 = c(34L, 44L), a3 = c(4L, 98L)), .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)); library(tidyr); gather(df1, id, val)`?

Comment: It still gives the error `Error in measure.attributes[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`.  I am using R 3.1.2

Comment: @akrun I found the culprit: [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/commit/882b48089c873516c485cf75e8108b04519ced4e) (which came without a version bump, hence our having the same version number). I'll add a note to my answer that this requires the latest development version.

Comment: Thanks for finding that.  Seems like I need to reinstall `tidyr`

Answer (score 0):

```
require(dplyr) # for mutate()
require(tidyr) # for gather()

d <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(23, 34),
  a2 = c(34, 44),
  a3 = c(4, 98)
  )

gather(d, id, val, a1:a3) %>%
  mutate(id = paste(row_number(), "id", sep = "_"))
```